# Setting Lenght Limit in editText in Java

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

In my Android app, I will take the name of the person with an `editText`. Then, I will send it to a `textView` to show that in the subsequent activities. But, I have a limited area. That's why I have to limit the length of the name. In XML, we can restrict the character length with a code called `maxLength`. However, I don't want to use it because I want to limit the text within the design limits.

I will visualize the reason why I don't want to use this method. Let's imagine that the person wants to use 8-Z(ZZZZZZZZ) as a name; on the other hand, another person wants to use 8-i(iiiiiiii). Of course, their actual length will be different in design. So, I want to limit the name based on its length on design instead of its character length. I'm waiting for your contributions and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one line `TextView` with scaling the `TextSize` and fit the whole text in its layout bounds.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8dp"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="12dp"
    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1dp" 
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxLines="1"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I tried your advice but I'm not looking for something like that. I want to take input from the users and show all of them in an activity with the same text size. I have already had `android:singleLine` and `android:textSize`; but, I want to limit their input's length based on my UI design. So, as I mentioned in my question, I don't want to use `maxLength`, I want to find something else which is a more effective way than that.